# Algorithm for generating a Collection with Subcollections

Tags: laravel, collections

What I need to do is distribute my users by country_id.

So, I have :

```
$users->groupBy('country_id')
```

that gives me a Collection of small Collections of user within the same country.

Thing is small collection have different size.

What should be the best way of filling main Collection???

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve? What result do you expect?

Comment: I want to have a collection order like that: FrenchUser, SpanishUser, MexicanUser, ColombianUser, FrenchUser, SpanishUser, MexicanUser, ColombianUser, FrenchUser, SpanishUser, MexicanUser, ColombianUser, FrenchUser, SpanishUser, MexicanUser, ColombianUser, etc.... this is an example, countries vary.

Comment: I just don't want 2 user from the same country to be close

Comment: At the end, I will chunk list by 3, and I want to avoid in most of the case to have 2 users from the same country

Comment: So you only want *one collection*, in which there are *one user per country for each cuntry*?

Comment: Nop. After generating my collection I will chunk it every 3 objects. So 1 country should be repeated every 3 items

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, if you have a better way, please post!

```
        $userGroups = $this->championship->users->groupBy($this->groupBy); // Collection of Collection
        // Get biggest group.
        $max = $this->getMaxCompetitorByEntity($userGroups);
        $competitors = new Collection();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
            foreach ($userGroups as $userGroup) {
                $competitor = $userGroup->get($i);
                if (isset($competitor)) {
                    $competitors->push($userGroup->get($i));
                    echo $userGroup->get($i)->association->name . "<br/>";
                }
            }
        }
```

with

```
 /**
 * @param $userGroups
 * @return int
 */
private function getMaxCompetitorByEntity($userGroups):int
{
    $max = 0;
    foreach ($userGroups as $userGroup) {
        if (sizeof($userGroup) > $max) {
            $max = sizeof($userGroup);
        }

    }
    return $max;
}
```